# Applying for two Assistant Professor job posts on different subjects, but very related

Tags: job-search, job, assistant-professor

I am preparing my application for two job positions for the same university on different subjects, but they are highly related to each other. Based on my knowledge and experience (PhD in applied machine learning and statistics), I am capabale of teaching both. Suppose, one job position is for assistant professor on statistics and the other is on statistical programming. Two different subjects, but (very) interrelated.

The question is: will it be detrimnetal or in anyway seen as a counterintuitive, or negative to my chances if I apply for both these positions given that they are so close to each other and is for the same university?

Comment: I'm guessing this is missing the important detail that both jobs have the same employer.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14646/is-it-acceptable-to-apply-for-two-different-postdoc-positions-in-the-same-instit

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12414/should-i-simultaneously-apply-for-multiple-jobs-in-different-ranks-at-the-same-u

Comment: I've done this lots of times.  I usually just fill in each application as if the other one didn't exist.  But emulating my approach is not necessarily the optimal strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both jobs are in the same department: Ask the contact person. (If that contact person won't be on the hiring committee, then get in contact with someone who is.)

Assuming both jobs are in different departments: (IMO) Departments are independent and two applications will not overlap at the department level. (They will, of course, overlap within the university.) I see no reason not to apply for both.

(Traditionally, this would have been easy: You'd write two applications, put them inside two envelopes, and put both envelopes inside a third along with an extra covering letter explaining that you're applying for both positions. You could even mention in both applications that you're applying for both positions. These days, with automated systems, this might not be possible. Depending on the system you're being forced to use, perhaps you can manage something along these lines.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will be detrimental or not, but if the two positions are in the same division of a college or university, the same Dean likely is the final decision maker for both positions.  If there is a search committee for each position, there is a chance that there may be faculty with cross-appointments who sit on both committees.

I see possibilities for an advantage here, for you and for both departments, with your recruitment for one department changing the search for the other department in subtle ways if they get together to strategize, but don't see a real way for you to directly make this happen.

While you haven't brought this up, it would be a bad move to try to hide your application to one department from the other department.  You don't need to bring it up, but if asked, be frank about it.